# Images in multiple source DIV, add/replace the current image from each DIV onClick to target DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I could manage to get all images from each source div to target div,after onClick on each image in source div (which overlaps is fine).(this can be seen by "Inspect Element" in the browser)

Q: How to add/replace single flower image from each respective vase(source div) to collection(target div (id="p1")),So that the target div has three images, one from each source div at a time.

I need only single image from each source div to target div.How to figure this out.
Somebody please help.

---

**Code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .main {
        height: 400px;
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    .p1 {
        position:relative;
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        background-size: 100% auto;
        border-style: outset;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
    .p1 img{
        position:absolute;

        background-size: 100% auto;
        border-style: outset;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }

    .images {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .divs{
        float:left;
        padding:20px;
        margin:5px;
        border:solid #000 thin;
        }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="p1" class="p1"><img src="" alt="" /><p align="center"><b>COLLECTION</b></p></div>
        <div id="p2" class="divs">
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj0" name="obj" onclick="myvase1(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-511058.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj1" name="obj" onclick="myvase1(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-380016.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj2" name="obj" onclick="myvase1(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-293063.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj3" name="obj" onclick="myvase1(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-611834.jpg" /></br><b>vase1</b>
        </div>
        <div id="p3" class="divs">
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj0" name="obj" onclick="myvase2(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-771362.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj1" name="obj" onclick="myvase2(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-435833.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj2" name="obj" onclick="myvase2(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-661694.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj3" name="obj" onclick="myvase2(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-413011.jpg" /></br><b>vase2</b>
        </div>
        <div id="p4" class="divs">
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj0" name="obj" onclick="myvase3(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-392478.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj1" name="obj" onclick="myvase3(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-558351.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj2" name="obj" onclick="myvase3(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-630909.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj3" name="obj" onclick="myvase3(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-302761.jpg" /></br><b>vase3</b>
        </div>
        <script>

            function myvase1(id) {               
                    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id = one height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   

            }
             function myvase2(id) {               
                    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id = one height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   

            }
            function myvase3(id) {               
                    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id = one height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   

            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use separate ids for each image from each group. Then check if image with this id already exist. If yes - you need to change `src` attribute only.

```
function myvase1(id) {               
    var img = document.getElementById("one");
    if (img) {
        img.setAttribute("src", id.getAttribute("src"));
    } else {
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' id ='one' height=100px ;width=100px;/>";   
    }
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rbrv727t/).

I believe, solution can be much prettier, but I don't know what's your final goal.

Comment: Check this out: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rbrv727t/1/). I would do smth like that.